# UWP app as wcf server?

Tags: wcf, .net-core, uwp

What I observed is:

- The System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost class is not available in .NET Core for UWP;
- Duplex channel is PlatformNotSupportedException that doesn't support wcf callback.

So I wonder, UWP apps are designed to only work as WCF client? Isn't it possible to host a wcf service in a UWP app to make it like a server?

Comment: Assuming the UWP is positioned as a type of CLIENT technique only.... ??

Answer (score 0):

UWP Application worked in with limited folder access and limited capabilities.

To Host WCF Service it needs to act as web server. It does not have that capability included.

Below are the capabilities supported.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations